# register field with php acf not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i want to create custom field in my ACF plugin, but with PHP.
So i tried the below function but nothing happened, can anyone please help me

```
function register_custom_acf_fields() {
if ( function_exists( 'acf_add_local_field_group' ) ) {
    // ACF Group: People
    acf_add_local_field_group( array (
        'key'      => 'group_person_details',
        'title'    => 'Person Details',
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param'    => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value'    => 'person',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order'            => 0,
        'position'              => 'normal',
        'style'                 => 'default',
        'label_placement'       => 'top',
        'instruction_placement' => 'label',
        'hide_on_screen'        => '',
    ) );
    // First name
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_first_name',
        'label'        => 'First Name',
        'name'         => 'first_name',
        'type'         => 'text',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 1,
    ) );
    // Middle name
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_middle_name',
        'label'        => 'Middle Name',
        'name'         => 'middle_name',
        'type'         => 'text',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 0,
    ) );
    // Last name
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_last_name',
        'label'        => 'Last Name',
        'name'         => 'last_name',
        'type'         => 'text',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 1,
    ) );
    // Image
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'           => 'field_image',
        'label'         => 'Image',
        'name'          => 'image',
        'type'          => 'image',
        'parent'        => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions'  => '',
        'required'      => 0,
        'return_format' => 'array',
        'preview_size'  => 'thumbnail',
        'library'       => 'all',
        'min_width'     => 0,
        'min_height'    => 0,
        'max_width'     => 0,
        'max_height'    => 0,
    ) );
    // Office
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_office',
        'label'        => 'Office',
        'name'         => 'office',
        'type'         => 'text',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 0,
    ) );
    // E-mail
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_email',
        'label'        => 'E-mail',
        'name'         => 'email',
        'type'         => 'email',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 0,
    ) );
    // Office Phone
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'          => 'field_phone',
        'label'        => 'Phone',
        'name'         => 'phone',
        'type'         => 'text',
        'parent'       => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required'     => 0,
    ) );
    // Affiliation
    acf_add_local_field( array(
        'key'             => 'field_affiliation',
        'label'           => 'Affiliation',
        'name'            => 'affiliation',
        'type'            => 'taxonomy',
        'parent'          => 'group_person_details',
        'instructions'    => '',
        'required'        => 0,
        'taxonomy'        => 'affiliation',
        'field_type'      => 'multi_select',      // UI (checkbox, multi-select, select, radio)
        'allow_null'      => 0,             // Can select a blank value
        'load_save_terms' => 1,             // Persist using term relationships table
        'return_format'   => 'object',      // or 'object'
        'add_term'        => 0,             // Can the user add new terms?
    ) );
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_acf_fields' );
```

Comment: Is there a reason, that you need to create it with php? 
If so, you can always just export it as PHP from the UI.

Comment: Yes, actually i want to create a plugin, where it create the same fields in all my other sites. I dont want to use import function.

Comment: thats what i mean - you can create it in the UI, and then export it as PHP - put the exportet code whereever. and delete the things again from the UI? 
But if you need to do it this way I guess you need to change your action to : add_action('acf/init', 'register_custom_acf_fields');

Comment: unless you have the old ACF of course

Comment: @Stender, thanks for the info, i exported the fields as php code, and deleted the UI fields. Next i pasted the exact code in my `function.php`, now what ?

Comment: that should do it? you should be able to put that in functions.php anywhere that you want the fields - are the fields not working now, and did they work when you had created them through the UI?

Comment: I think i am doing it wrong, so i need to include any acf file as well? like include_once(plugins_url().'advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php' );

Comment: you shouldn't need to, if the plugin is installed - it should be able to run it.

Comment: if it is a test enviroment, you can var dump etc. to see it you even access the function -

Comment: can you paste the updated php that you have put in your functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163627/discussion-between-awsme-sandy-and-stender).

Comment: So how did your discussion turn out? :) I'm encountering the same problem as the OP: I exported my ACF field groups to PHP, created a function from the code, put it into my site-specific plugin file and hooked it with the `acf/init` action. The ACF field groups created in the UI worked perfectly but they disappear when I try to create them within my plugin :/

Don't know if it matters, but I am using the free version of ACF.